# Javascript - checking whether a condition met in Array forEach

Tags: javascript

```
var myStringArray = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"], foundResult = false;

myStringArray.forEach(function(currentString) {
    if (/\d+/.test(currentString)) {
        console.log("Number found");
        foundResult = true;
    }
});

if(foundResult === false) {
    console.log("Number NOT found");
}
```

**This piece of code is to demonstrate the problem.** I have to use an extra variable to check whether there was a match or not. Is there any elegant way to handle this without the variable?

**Edit:** I know I can use `some`, but I would like to match the no match case as well as seen in the code's last `if` condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use some method:

```
if(["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"].some(function(i){return /\d+/.test(i)})){
    // if matched
} else {
    // handle no match
}
```

Comment: How do I handle if there is no match? That is why I explicitly have a condition at the end.

Comment: some method will return true or false based on if there was any match or not

Comment: better to split into two `var isFound = ["abcd", "efgh", "ijkl"].some(function(i){return /\d+/.test(i)})` , more readable

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that uses forEach is:

```
var a = ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ijkl'];
var r;

if (a.forEach(function(a){r = r || /\d/.test(a)}) || r) {
 alert('found a number');

} else if (r === false) {
 alert('no numbers');
}
```

but likely any UA that supports *forEach* will also support *some*, and *some* is also probably more efficient as it will stop at the first result of `true`.